# Sorting eigen values and corresponding eigen vectors

Tags: python, sorting, eigenvector

For a matrix A, I have a set of eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors, obtained using the standard method, `eigvals, eigvecs = la.eig(A)` after importing `scipy.linalg as la`.
The eigenvalues are sorted using `np.sort(eigvals, axis=-0)`.
How do we rearrange the corresponding eigenvectors.

Comment: I'm a novice to python.The solution to this naive problem is found in the following link. (http://www.physics.utah.edu/~detar/lessons/python/numpy_eigen/node2.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you need is to get the list of sorted indexes, then take eigenvectors and eigenvalues in that order using `np.argsort`.

It would be something like:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg as la

A =  np.random.rand(3, 3)
eigvals, eigvecs = la.eig(A)
sorted_indexes = np.argsort(eigvals)
eigvals = eigvals[sorted_indexes]
eigvecs = eigvecs[:,sorted_indexes]
```

P.S.: seems @srikrishna already posted a link with the solution. I will maintain the response stays in Stackoverflow.